# How to create an ArrayList that can store 50 strings in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to limit the arraylist to 50. but i dont know how.

here's my code
Object1.java

```
public class Object1 {

    public String seat_no, id;


    public Object1(String seat_no, String id) {

        this.seat_no = seat_no;
        this.id = id;

    }
}
```

main.java

```
private ArrayList<Object1> list;

list = new ArrayList<Object1>();
```

Comment: You are saying list of strings but are creating list of `Object1`s, not so clear.

Comment: why don't you use a array for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tempting as it may sound, I'd advise against extending `ArrayList` or any other `List` implementation, because then you'll be limiting yourself to using only one type of list. What happens if next time you want to limit a `LinkedList` and not an `ArrayList`? would you extend `LinkedList` too? what happens if you want to limit, basically, an arbitrary implementation of `List`?

What you're looking for already exists. You can use Commons Collections and wrap a list with a predicate:

```
class SizePredicate implements Predicate {
    private List list;
    private int maxSize;

    public SizePredicate(List l, int size) {
        list = l;
        maxSize = size;
    }

    public boolean evaluate(Object obj) {
        if (list.size() >= maxSize) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Your message here");
        }
        list.add(obj);
    }
}

...

List list = new LinkedList();  // Or, really, any implementation of list.

List maxList = ListUtils.predicatedList(list, new SizePredicate(list, 50));
```

Using the design above, you can use the same `Predicate` instance to limit any sort of list. You can also extend it to handle any sort of collection...

... Without the need to extend any JDK class.

Comment: +1. I completely agree on your advice and your solution is in my opinion more elegant.

Comment: thats right composition should always be preferred over extension.

Comment: Actually, this isn't composition; it's decoration. The decorator is provided by Commons Collections. The Predicate implementation hold a reference to the list only because it has to check its length (the `Predicate` interface allows only one argument to the evaluation method).

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is to extend the ArrayList to LimitedArrayList and overwrite the add methods.

```
public class LimitedArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

private final int capacity;

public LimitedArrayList(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
    this.capacity = capacity;

}
@Override
public boolean add(E e) {
    if(size()>=capacity){
        throw new ListFullExcption();
    }
    return super.add(e);
}

    // there are more add methods to override but i will let you figure that out.
}
```

Comment: What happens when tomorrow he wants to limit a different implementation of `List`? A wrapper would be a better design pattern to follow here, IMO... see my answer below.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. how do i use this in order to get the 25th index and assign a string of seat_no and an id to it and the rest should be blank.

Comment: The method public E set(int index, E element)
Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option here :

You can create an array of String, here you will have the option to set the max size.
Or

you can create a new class which will extend ArrayList and override its add() method.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class UserInformation {

    private String userId;
    private String name;
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public void setUsername(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }  
    }
```

to add the data

```
public List<UserInformation> userInfo= new ArrayList<UserInformation>();
    public UserInformation objuserinfo= null;


              for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
               {
                 objuserinfo = new UserInformation();
                objuserinfo.setUserId("ID");
                objuserinfo.setUsername("name");
                userInfo.add(objuserinfo);
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

cant you just do

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(size);
```

Comment: This won't limit the number of items. It'd set the initial capacity, which is good for memory management purposes under some circumstances: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)